# what is the difference between "zeroconf" and Apache Tribes?

Tags: zeroconf

What is the advantage to use zeroconf over apache tribes?

Answer (score 1):

viji, the two are very different technologies at different levels of a networking stack. Zeroconf helps devices get network addresses and discover services on a network, while Tribes lets Java programs talk to each other by sending serialized objects back and forth. It is a messaging framework at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

they aren't even the same technologies in function one is a service discovery protocol using multicast dns the other is apparently a clustered messaging server. What you really need to research is [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/) if you want a generic clustering solution for Java programs.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tribes Cluster

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/tribes/introduction.html

> SUMMARY:Tribes is a messaging
>   framework with group communication
>   abilities. Tribes allows you to send
>   and receive messages over a network,
>   it also allows for dynamic discovery
>   of other nodes in the network.

Zeroconf

[Zero Configuration Networking](http://www.zeroconf.org/)

> SUMMARY:The IETF Zeroconf Working
>   Group was chartered September
>   1999...The specification for IPv4 Link-Local Addressing is complete, but
>   the work to improve network
>   ease-of-use (Zero Configuration
>   Networking) continues. That means
>   making it possible to take two laptop
>   computers, and connect them with a
>   crossover Ethernet cable, and have
>   them communicate usefully using IP,
>   without needing a man in a white lab
>   coat to set it all up for you.
>   Zeroconf is not limited to networks
>   with just two hosts, but as we scale
>   up our technologies to larger
>   networks, we always have to be sure we
>   haven't forgotten the two-devices (and
>   no DHCP server) case.

Comment: this guide is not in Engilsh.
BTW i know about zeroconf. I want to know what are the advantages in using zeroconf rather using apache tribes clustering?

Comment: tribes is a messaging framework that happens to do clustering, zeroconf/bonjour is a discovery protocol using multicast dns they aren't comparable, it is like asking should I use GCC or MS Word to cook my dinner. tribes isn't for doing clustering it just happens to be able to cluster its messaging service.